# How to install android application on windows

Tags: android

Hi just downloaded an android application from a website (with .apk  extension). Is there any way we can use it on windows O.S.?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, as it's not programming related. However, the answer is no. It's an Android app, not a Windows app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the emulator to run the application that comes with the android development sdk.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: Without using emulator is there built-in software is there..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and then you can use android emulator to install the .apk file.

Comment: But i dont think its possible bcoz i tried..

Comment: @rajaram it is possible. what is the problem ?